# How can I list/manage the currently installed certificates on Lumia 930?

Tags: lumia, settings, 8.1-update-1, nokia-lumia-930, certificate

So I would like to see all default and additional certificates on my Lumia 930 with WP8.1 Update 1. I did not find any menu in settings where I could list / add / delete certificates.

Just for example what I mean, in android there is a setting that shows me all the certs:
[image: Trusted credentials in Android]

**Where is this function in WP8? How can I see installed certs?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft published the App "certificates". [Windows Phone Store: App "Certificates"](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/certificates/c356e3f2-451f-4d82-87df-e53b644bec01)

But in there, you can only list the certificates. You can't delete or add certificates.

Comment: I am still looking for a way to delete a certain certificate, but this is something :)

Comment: I think only a hard reset will get rid of unwanted certificates for now.